# Actionbar on Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been asked to look at getting an existing app working on an Android phone running Andrdoid 2.3.6 ( API 10? ).

The app currently used the ICS ActionBar, is there any way of doing this with API 10?
I dont think even ActionBar Sherlock goes down to that API level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I dont think even ActionBar Sherlock goes down to that API level.

No, ABS supports everything from Android 2.0 (API 5) upwards.

Answer (score 1):

ActionSherlockBar, supports almost all version.

I actually used it extensively on 2.x devices!